# Age gate not showing on home page

Tags: 8, hooks, users

I am working on a client's website and need to implement this [age gate](http://avp3.azureedge.net/readme.html) on it. The problem is it only shows on a specific url/page but not on other pages. Been looking for solutions since past 2 days but couldn't find anything on google about it.

This is what I did:

Added the shown below in `html.html.twig` and uploaded the relevant css and html. But the age gate popup only shows on www.xyz.com/?AvpClearCookie=1 but not on the www.xyz.com

```
<!-- Age Gate: START -->
<script defer="defer" async>
(function(doc, url, tag) {
var js=doc.createElement(tag),fjs=doc.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];js.src=url;fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs.nextSibling);
}(document, '//avp3.azureedge.net/api/ballantines/avp/?language=en&callback=test_cb', 'script'));
</script><div id="avp"></div>
<!-- Age Gate: END -->
```

I was trying to show it on home page but with the very limited knowledge I have about drupal it seeming difficult for me to get it done. Really appreciate if anybody could show me some light on this.

Comment: Have you tried in an anonymous browser session, or another browser? Since this script apparently sets a cookie (it stores your age) it makes sense that the for subsequent page requests it would not show up. It might very well work on the homepage if you visit the page for the first time.

Comment: Yes I tried it in a private window, other pc with different internet connection and also via vpn. I also tried it on a wordpress site but same thing happened there. Can I provide the website's link?

Comment: @Neograph734 please could you take a moment and help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a cache issue, so you can try to externalize your script and call it with random parameter

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/my/script.js?itok=1561313215" defer="defer" async></script>
```

You can generate a random value with php with microtime by sample

Try it and let us know if helps you

Comment: Just looked at the console and it is showing this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://avp3.azureedge.net/api/globalstorage/?1503387986558. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.montanawines.co.nz.php56-26.phx1-1.websitetestlink.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: it's a header blocking request who don't come from same host :/ if you have access to server side configuration you can change this instructions , or add your script on same domain

Comment: I have no idea how to fix this. Could you please guide me?